# Why is the horizontal scrollbar missing on my DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` comprising only a `DataGridView`, set to dock to fill the `UserControl`. The dgv's `ScrollBars` property is set to `Both`, but yet when I dynamically load the dgv into a panel on a client form, no horizontal scrollbar is displayed. I found this question, but none of my columns is frozen. Where is my scrollbar?

I am data binding the dgv, and it's columns collection well exceeds the visible width.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So my simple example works fine for showing the scroll bars automatically.  Here's what I did:

I've got a `UserControl` which just has a `DataGridView` in it, `Dock` is set to **Full**.

It's got one public function I added that looks like this:

```
public void SetBinding(object theSource)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = theSource;
}
```

just to set up the binding against my datasource.

My test form's pretty simple and it just looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    List<Stuff> list = new List<Stuff>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindSomeStuff();
    }

    private void BindSomeStuff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        {
            list.Add(new Stuff
            {
                Column1 = i.ToString() + "Column1 Data",
                Column2 = i.ToString() + "Column2 Data",
                Column3 = i.ToString() + "Column3 Data",
                Column4 = i.ToString() + "Column4 Data",
                Column5 = i.ToString() + "Column5 Data",
                Column6 = i.ToString() + "Column6 Data",
                Column7 = i.ToString() + "Column7 Data",
                Column8 = i.ToString() + "Column8 Data",
            }
            );
        }
        bs.DataSource = list;
        userControl11.SetBinding(bs);
    }
}
```

And then there's a simple class to hold some dummy data that looks like:

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Column4 { get; set; }
    public string Column5 { get; set; }
    public string Column6 { get; set; }
    public string Column7 { get; set; }
    public string Column8 { get; set; }
}
```

My `UserControl` is placed on the form and both scroll bars show up.

I've made no other changes to any properties of anything for the `DataGridView`, the `UserControl` that it is part of or the `Form` that holds that `UserControl`.  I wonder if you have something else set that I don't.

Comment: Turns out I had to dock the `UserControl` in the panel I load it into as well.

Comment: Shouldn't matter about that.  My example doesn't dock the user control but I'm glad you've fixed it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario **UserControl + DataGridView + missing Horizontal ScrollBar**
Just set the `Frozen = false` in column editor of DataGridView for each column.
And yes,

```
  dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```